# Oracle Find duplicate records that are similar but aren't exact matches

Tags: sql, oracle, search, duplicates, search-engine

I'm trying to find a way to search a text field to identify rows that could be similar so I can identify if they are duplicates that should be merged. For example if my data looks like this:

**MyText_Column**

1. Bob
2. Bobby
3. Robert
4. Jane
5. Janey
6. Janie
7. Joe
8. John
9. Johnathan

A GROUP BY won't work because none of the values are exactly the same, but if I could have a query that would return a list of the likelihood that one row is similar would be great. Maybe there's a better layout but what I am imagining is a result like this:

**Query Result**

Search Compare Likely_Match

1. Bob    Bobby   96%
2. Bob    Robert  12%
3. Bob    Jane    0%
4. Bob    Janey   0%
5. .....
6. Jane   Janey   87%
7. Jane   Janie   69%
8. Jane   Joe     12%

Then with result like that I could sort by likelihood and and visually scan to determine if the results are duplicates or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [UTL_MATCH package](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/u_match.htm) has a couple of methods to do that-- my guess is that you would want to use the Jaro-Winkler similarity algorithm.  Something like

```
SELECT a.mytext_column search,
       b.mytext_column compare,
       utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity( a.mytext_column, b.mytext_column ) similarity
  FROM table_name a,
       table_name b
 WHERE a.<<primary key>> != b.<<primary key>>
 ORDER BY utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity( a.mytext_column, b.mytext_column ) desc
```

That will generate a result set of N * (N-1) rows which may be unwieldy depending on the number of rows in the original data set.  You may want to restrict things by only returning the best matches for a particular search term or only returning the rows that have a similarity score greater than some threshold.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the [`SOUNDEX`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions167.htm) function.